# How to compute the number of Bills / Coins when making change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to compute the numbers of coins when making change. My problem with my code is, that it does not work for the last coins (1cent, 2cent), although I implemented them in my code.

[Link to the code](http://jsfiddle.net/eLzfd6tt/)

**my html code**

```
  <input type="number" class="calculate" id="moneytochange" placeholder="€">
  <p id="e500"> </p>
  <p id="e200"> </p>
  <p id="e100"> </p>
  <p id="e50"> </p>
  <p id="e20"> </p>
  <p id="e10"> </p>
  <p id="e5"> </p>
  <p id="e2"> </p>
  <p id="e1"> </p>
  <p id="e05"> </p>
  <p id="e02"> </p>
  <p id="e01"> </p>
  <p id="e005"> </p>
  <p id="e002"> </p>
  <p id="e001"> </p>
```

(the "e" is there because of the "e" in Euro )

**my jquery code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".calculate").bind("keyup change input paste", function(){

  var billsAndCoins = [500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1,   0.05, 0.02, 0.01];
  var number = {};

  var money = $("#moneytochange").val();
  billsAndCoins.forEach(function(i) {
    number[i] = (money - (money % i))/ i;
    $("#e" + i.toString().replace('.','')).html(number[i] + " * " + i);
    money = money % i;
    });

  });
});
```

**my css code**

```
input {
text-align: center;
font-size: 3vw;
margin: 0 17%;
width: 60%;
border: none;
border-bottom: 4px solid #7C4DFF;
outline: none;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
padding: 1% 3% 1% 3%;
transition: border-radius 0.3s ease-out;
opacity: 50%;
}
input:focus {
border-radius: 1vw;
}
```

Comment: _" it does not work for the last coins (1cent, 2cent)"_ What is expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that it fails for the cents is that the remaining money becomes something like 0.0099999999856 instead of 0.01 because of floating point inaccuracies.

Here is your code converted to calculate with integer cents instead of decimals, thereby avoiding the floating point problems:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".calculate").bind("keyup change input paste", function(){

    var billsAndCoins = [50000, 20000, 10000, 5000, 2000, 1000, 500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1];
    var number = {};

    var money = Math.round($("#moneytochange").val() * 100);
    billsAndCoins.forEach(function(entry) {
      number[entry] = (money - money % entry)/ entry;
      $("#e" + entry).html(number[entry] + " * " + (entry/100));
      money = money % entry;
    });

  });
});
```

```css
input {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 3vw;
 margin: 0 17%;
 width: 60%;
 border: none;
 border-bottom: 4px solid #7C4DFF;
 outline: none;
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 padding: 1% 3% 1% 3%;
 transition: border-radius 0.3s ease-out;
 opacity: 50%;
}
input:focus {
 border-radius: 1vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="calculate" id="moneytochange" placeholder="€">
<p id="e50000">0 *</p>
<p id="e20000">0 *</p>
<p id="e10000">0 *</p>
<p id="e5000">0 *</p>
<p id="e2000">0 *</p>
<p id="e1000">0 *</p>
<p id="e500">0 *</p>
<p id="e200">0 *</p>
<p id="e100">0 *</p>
<p id="e50">0 *</p>
<p id="e20">0 *</p>
<p id="e10">0 *</p>
<p id="e5">0 *</p>
<p id="e2">0 *</p>
<p id="e1">0 *</p>
```

Comment: Do you know how I can create divs (for example styled like a 500 Euro bill) based on the amount of them.

Comment: For that you would need to find images, and then reference them as CSS `background-image: url(http://example.com)`. But since this is quite a different question, I suggest you open a new question for that, tagging it with `css` so you get those specialists on StackOverflow to look at it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'll go as far as to blame JavaScript for rounding it automatically.

Considder using cents rather than entire euro, then devide it by 100 to get the euros.

I know from experience that some grocery stores also use cents rather than whole euros - It's a common thing that integers are prefered over decimals

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".calculate").bind("keyup change input paste", function(){

    var billsAndCoins = [50000, 20000, 10000, 5000, 2000, 1000, 500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1];
    var number = {};

    var money = $("#moneytochange").val();
    $("#change").html("");
    var cents = money * 100;
    billsAndCoins.forEach(function(entry) {
        number[entry] = (cents - (cents % entry))/ entry;
        if(number[entry]>0) $("#change").append("<p>" + entry/100 + " * " + number[entry] + "</p>")
            cents = cents % entry;
      });
   });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eLzfd6tt/2/